# Best ways to store user preferences in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, redux, local-storage

I'm working on a React/Redux app and I need to store several user preferences. 
And I cannot find a best practices to acomplish storing a great volumen of persistent data.
For what I know the options are cookies or localStorage or data base via endpoint (not good for this example).
What is the best performant way to do this?

Edit:
I have a table with n values, and the user can check all the rows that he want. There are different filters in the whole application too. And the client want to have persistent data, if he close the tab, it should everything be where the user left it.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, this question is an off-topic question because there is no "best way" in every problem, but it might have a "suitable way", please ask for what you want and give us an example so we can suggest you the right answer.

Comment: @ilumin sorry about that, it was my first question here. I left an edit explaining more of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Depends really on the business case and what you want to achieve with the app. The way you present it suggest to store in the localStorage. Storing reducer in cookies is not good idea because generally the reducers are quite large and the cookies have limited size(4093 bytes).